# jquery selector as a custom attribute

Tags: jquery

I am Using jquery how can I trigger an alert when mouseover the element with the data-code=GB atribute?

I tried this with no luck...

```
  $(".jvectormap-container path[data-code='GB']").mouseover(function(){
     alert('test');
  });
```

Thank you

Comment: code is here - http://jsbin.com/opedih/1/edit

Comment: Is the actual name of the element `path`?

Comment: Does reversing the quotes make a difference? `$('.jvectormap-container path[data-code="GB"]')`

Comment: I tried reversing the quote marks but no luck :-(

Comment: You don't even need the quotes in the attribute selector, since there are no special characters in the attribute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to use standard parameter of the jVectorMap `onRegionOver`? Your code won't work in IE, because there are no `path` element in IE, it uses `shape` instead.

Answer (score 1):

With slight modification, its working for me.
I added -

```
<head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.jvectormap-container path[data-code="GB"]').bind('mouseover', function(){
       alert('test');
     });
   });
  </script>
</head>
```

Working copy is here: http://jsbin.com/uwatiz/5/edit

Answer (score 0):

You have the path inside a div. Which is something wrong. With proper usage of path your js code works fine.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" class="jvectormap-container">
 <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" data-code='GB' />
</svg>
```

Comment: I cannot take the svg out of the DIV. But I did add xlmns and version and the class to the SVG element. But still no luck :-(

     $('.jvectormap-container svg:first').attr('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
     $('.jvectormap-container svg:first').attr('version', '1.1');
     $('.jvectormap-container svg:first').attr('class', 'jvectormap-container');

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    $(".jvectormap-container").filter("path[data-code='GB']").on('mouseover',function(){
        alert('test');
    });
});
```